# img src with v-bind not displaying image

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to display a dynamic image with v-bind and it s not working
in template tag:

```
         <img v-bind:src="test" />
```

in script tag :

```
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      imagesref: "",
      test: '~/assets/captures/ref_01_03_2022_17_05_21/@DHRD-52484/user language check dates in different language/1.png'
          };
```

I tired to use the test path on an img tag to check if there's something wrong with the path but it worked fine.
how can i fix this

Comment: You are using a path not a URI. try `https://via.placeholder.com/500x500`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-bind:src` works as expected. The problem is your path makes no sense in the context of your web page.

To translate a project path into a web path, use [`vue-loader`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html). Namely:

```
test: require('./relative/path/to/image.png')
```

Or you can make use of the existing [transform rules](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules).

**Note:** This might vary based on configuration, but in a standard Vue project, replacing `~/assets` with `@/assets` should fix the problem, without needing `require()`.

Comment: thanks @tao ,using require did work for me but is there anyway i can use the require after an API call ?I'm retrieving paths just like the test path from an API call and populating the imagesref variable and i want to render the images after that API call

Comment: @Mohamed, instantiate the variable holding the `src` with an empty string. In the above case: `test: ''`. Put a `v-if` on the image `<img v-if="test" :src="test" />`. When you want to render the image, update `test` with the correct `src`.